# How do I downgrade from VisualSVN Professional to Community?

Tags: visualsvn

I recently installed VisualSVN in with Visual Studio 2015.
But inadvertanly I must have put professional on there.

If you go to "Tools -> Extensions and Updates" in VS 2015, the Uninstall button for VisualSVN is uninstalled.  But I uninstalled it form windows programs.

Then if I go to:
https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/purchase/
and click download for Community License and then install it, and then open VS 2015, I still get the message:
"All functions of VisualSVN are disabled because your evaluation period is expired".

How can I get rid of this and install the free community version?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [licensing](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/purchase/) page:

> Community License can only be used on a computer that is **not a member of an Active Directory domain**.

Your computer is a member of AD domain, therefore Community license is not applicable. If it was a non-domain or workgroup computer, the Community license would've been activated automatically.